# String manipulation in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure

I am new to Clojure. I have a java hashmap which has integer as keys and array list as values. The map is:  {1=[Delhi, Goa, Mumbai], 2=[hello, world, the, world, is, awesome]}. I want to replace world with night and hello with good. I am doing something like this.

Clojure code:

```
(doseq [[k v] m]
  (when (= k 2)
    (doseq [s v]
      (if (= s "world")
        (def a(clojure.string/replace(s #"world" "night"))))
      (if (= s "hello")
        (def b(clojure.string/replace(s #"hello" "good")))))))
```

This doesn't work perfectly. Also when I try to print the value of a and b, it shows

```
#object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x31791dc5 Unbound: #'com.example.core/a] and #object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x31791dc5 Unbound: #'com.example.core/b].
```

How can I see the value of a i.e. night and b i.e. good. Is there any other way of string manipulation? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You should start by reading a book like Clojure for the Brave and True, or another online resource. You're trying to write Clojure like it's Java, and that is going to make your life painful.

Comment: Only def in toplevel.  Use let instead.

Answer (score 3):

combination of `update` and `replace` would do the trick:

```
user> (def data {1 ["Delhi" "Goa" "Mumbai"]
                 2 ["hello" "world" "the" "world" "is" "awesome"]})

user> (update data 2 #(replace {"world" "night" "hello" "good"} %))
;;=> {1 ["Delhi" "Goa" "Mumbai"], 2 ["good" "night" "the" "night" "is" "awesome"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of different ways to approach this. Let's say you've got

```clj
(def data {1 ["hello" "world"]})
```

### The easy way

```clj
(def modified (assoc data 1 ["good" "night"])) 
;; {1 ["good" "night"]}
```

This just returns a new data structure with the value at 1 swapped for a new vector of the appropriate elements. But that only works for fairly simple stuff where you know exactly what's in the vector.

### The less easy way

```
(def result
  (into (sorted-map)
        (map
          (fn [[k v]]
            (if (some #{"hello" "world"} v)
                [k (assoc (assoc v (.indexOf v "hello") "good") 
                          (.indexOf v "world") 
                          "night")]
                [k v]))
          (seq data))))

(print result) ; {1 ["good" "night"]}
```

Here, `seq` called on the map returns a lazy sequence of key/value tuples. We map over those with a function that checks for the values we want to replace and returns either a new key/value tuple with the words swapped at the appropriate indicies in the vector or the original if "hello"/"world" are not in the vector. Then `into` turns it back into a map.